# two nearly identical calls, one works one fails

Tags: c++, templates, cuda

I have these template functions for use inline on device with cuda

```
template <class T> __device__ inline T& cmin(T&a,T&b){return (a<b)?(a):(b);};
template <class T> __device__ inline T& cmax(T&a,T&b){return (a>b)?(a):(b);};
```

In the code I have

```
cmin(z[i],y[j])-cmax(x[i],z[j])
```

for int arrays x,y,and z.  I get the error:

> error: no instance of function template "cmax" matches the argument list
>
> ```
>       argument types are: (int, int)
> ```

I get the error for cmax but not cmin.  If I replace the cmax line with

```
#define cmax(a,b) ((a)>(b))?(a):(b)
```

that works just fine, but I don't want #defines, they are problematic.  What the heck is going on here?

EDIT:
here is the full calling function.  times is typedef int.

```
__global__ void compute_integral_y_isums(times * admit, times * discharge, times * Mx, times * isums, ar_size N){
    // computes the sums for each j
    // blocks on j,
    // threads on i since we will be summing over i.
    // sumation over J should be handled by either a different kernel or on the cpu.
    ar_index tid = threadIdx.x;
    ar_index i = blockIdx.x;                       // summing for patient i 
    ar_index j = threadIdx.x; // across other patients j
    __shared__ times cache[threadsPerBlock];

  times Iy = 0;
    while(j<N){
        // R code:  max(0,min(Mx[i],d3[j,'Discharge.time'])-max(d3[i,'Admission.time'],Mx[j]))
        times imin = cmin(Mx[i],discharge[j]);
        times imax = cmax(admit[i],Mx[j]);
        Iy += cmax(0,imin-imax);
        j += blockDim.x;
    }
    cache[tid] = Iy;

    __syncthreads(); 
    // reduce 
    /***REMOVED***/
}
```

Comment: You need to post more of your calling code- the types of x, y, z, for example. Something wrong with std::min and std::max?

Comment: Have you verified that there are no typos in your code? The error you're getting is from passing a non-int type in one of your params... perhaps you're passing a null ref and aren't realizing it?

Comment: It actually appears that CUDA can only handle one instance of a template function.

Comment: Not sure if the standard library is available in CUDA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If either `x` or `z` is a `const` array, their element type will be `const int`, which is not convertible to `int&`.

Try with:

```
template<class T> __device__ inline T cmin(const T& a, const T& b)
{
    return (a < b ? a : b);
}

template<class T> __device__ inline T cmax(const T& a, const T& b)
{
    return (a > b ? a : b);
}
```

If `T` is always a primitive type like `int`, you can even pass the parameters by value:

```
template<class T> __device__ inline T cmin(T a, T b)
{
    return (a < b ? a : b);
}

template<class T> __device__ inline T cmax(T a, T b)
{
    return (a > b ? a : b);
}
```

**EDIT:** @aschepler has the right answer.

Comment: it must be x that is constant because z is used in the call to cmin

Comment: If you need to use `cmax` and `cmin` on the left side of an assignment, you can make a separate overload that accepts `T&`.

Comment: @Moe, From the questioner's code sample, neither are `const` unless `times` is `typedefed` to `const int`, but then they would both be `const`. And the compiler would have to swap the calls to `cmax()` and `cmin()` *before* its semantic analysis, which I don't think it's allowed to do. I'm stumped.

Comment: @Jon, seeing things like `cmin(a, b) = c;` in C++ still makes my skin crawl after all those years. I'd rather not do that :)

Comment: This answered it.  Correct @Frédéric Hamidi there is no const business here, but the things that solved it was the passing by value. apparently cuda does not like pass by ref.

Comment: If the type is const, T will be deduced as a const type.  @Halpo: This is not the correct reason, even though it gave code that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 7):

```
Iy += cmax(0,imin-imax);
```

is not legal.  You can't bind the literal `0` to an `int&` reference (but you can to a `const int&` reference).

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful in **returning a reference**, if your functions also **take references** as arguments. You might return a **reference to a temporary**! Like in:

```
cmin(0,imin-imax);
```

which is probably ok for `int` and `float`, but dangerous for non-PODs.

Comment: If you're returning a reference to the parameter, you're guaranteed it will be available until the end of the full-expression containing the function call.  That's not the problem here.

Comment: Yes, sure. But I was thinking about `T &x = cmin(a+b,d+e); print(x);` (*boom*). If I see a *return-reference* I of course consider catching it *by reference*.

Comment: Well, perhaps you should rethink that; std::max takes by const& and returns by const&, for example.

Comment: @Roger: Hmm, thanks for making me double check. We should be careful with `std::min` as well. I added a clarification as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reverse the definition order please.

```
template <class T> __device__ inline T& cmax(T&a,T&b){return (a>b)?(a):(b);};
template <class T> __device__ inline T& cmin(T&a,T&b){return (a<b)?(a):(b);};
```

cmax then cmin. What is the outpout then ?

Answer (score 0):

Your cmax and cmin are taking non-const reference to the elements. Maybe your arrays are declared as const?

Hard to tell, because the example is not complete.

Comment: If the type is const, T will be deduced as a const type.  "T&" does *not* necessarily mean non-const! (Just like "-n" doesn't necessarily mean a negative result; -(-42) is positive!)

Comment: @Roger Pate Great. Now explain what happen if x[i] returns int& and z[j] returns const double&

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already have some active `defines` which pollute you namespace?Try renaming `cmin` and `cmax`, or `#undef cmin` and `#undef cmax`. Or run `g++ -E` to see the de-macrofied code.

Or add `::` namespace specifier:

```
::cmin(z[i],y[j])-::cmax(x[i],z[j])
```

Anyway, you only need all the `()` in defines. Nicer:

```
template  __device__ T& cmin(const T&a,const T&b){return a<b?a:b;};
```

And you probably do not need the `inline` for a template function neither.

Comment: You can incorporate more into a single answer, no need to post multiples.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my *comment* on the initial question: Yes, one should be careful if ona just passes through a reference from a parameter. Here is a complete illustration:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Thing {
    int data;
    Thing() { data = 42; }
    Thing(int val) { data = val; }
    Thing(const Thing& oth) { data = oth.data; }
    Thing& operator=(const Thing& oth)
      { if(this!=&oth) this->data = oth.data; return *this; }
    ~Thing() { data = 0; } // clear, destroy, release...
};

bool operator<(const Thing &a, const  Thing &b) { return a.data 
const T& refmin(const T &a, const T &b) // return a ref
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}


template
const T copymin(const T &a, const T &b) // return a copy
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

followed by

```
int main(int argc, const char* [])
{
    Thing a(11);
    Thing b(88);

    std::cerr << "Simple operation:" << std::endl;
    const Thing c = a + b;
    std::cerr << "  c:" << c.data << "  should be 99" << std::endl;

    std::cerr << "Working on temp expression (BAD):" << std::endl;
    const Thing &x = refmin(c, b-a); // '&x' will be gone after ';' 
    // the next line might crash:
    std::cerr << "  x:" << x.data << "  should be 77" << std::endl;

    std::cerr << "Working explicit side variable (OK):" << std::endl;
    const Thing &d = b-a;
    const Thing &y = refmin(c, d);  // '&y' is now same as '&d'
    std::cerr << "  d:" << d.data << "  should be 77" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "  y:" << y.data << "  should be 77" << std::endl;

    std::cerr << "Working on a copy (OK):" << std::endl;
    const Thing &z = copymin(c, b-a);
    std::cerr <<  z:" << z.data << "  should be 77" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./minreftest
Simple operation:
  c:99  should be 99
Working on temp expression (BAD):
  x:0  should be 77
Working explicit side variable (OK):
  d:77  should be 77
  y:77  should be 77
Working on a copy (OK):
  z:77  should be 77
```

On some machines it might even *segfault*, I guess. In `Thing`s destructor I reset `data` to `0`, but one could easily imagine more there.

So, when we do the *BAD* `refmin` call, we return a reference to a temporary. Which is destroyed after the `;`. So, when we try to output `&x`, it's already gone.